# How can we skip some part in the string using regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a string:

```
st="[~620cc13778d079432b9bc7b1:Hello WorldGuest]"
```

I just want the part after `":"` and before `"]"`. The part in between can have a maximum length of 64 characters.

The part after  `"[~"` is 24 character UUID.

So the resulting string would be `"Hello WorldGuest"`.

I'm using the following regex:

```
r"(\[\~[a-z0-9]{24}:)(?=.{0,64})"
```

But that is only matching the string till `":"`, I also want to match the ending `"]"`.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
>>> import re
>>> st = "[~620cc13778d079432b9bc7b1:Hello WorldGuest]"
```

Two simple ways:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^:]*:([^\]]*)\]',r'\1',st)
'Hello WorldGuest'
>>> st.partition(':')[-1].rstrip(']')
'Hello WorldGuest'
```

If you want to be super specific:

```
>>> re.sub(r'^\[~[a-z0-9]{24}:([^\]]{0,64})\]$',r'\1',st)
'Hello WorldGuest'
```

If you want to correct your pattern, you can do:

```
>>> m=re.search(r'(?:\[~[a-z0-9]{24}:)(?=([^\]]{0,64})\])', st)
>>> m.group(1)
'Hello WorldGuest'
```

Or with anchors:

```
>>> m=re.search(r'(?:^\[~[a-z0-9]{24}:)(?=([^\]]{0,64})\]$)', st)
>>> m.group(1)
'Hello WorldGuest'
```

---

Note:

I just used your regex for a UUID even though it is not correct. The *correct* regex for a UUID is:

```
[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}
```

But that would not match your example...